# Change SACL on Named Pipe

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, named-pipes

I have C++ code that change SACL of a folder as it is expected. The things become strange when I want to change SACL of an exsiting Named Pipe, the code executes successful but when I check it via `Get-Acl -Path \\.\pipe\lsass -Audit | fl` it returns error number 87 which is `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` and SACL does not work. The error may be caused by setting not zero to OVERLAPPED structure according to [MS Support Site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/prb-error-invalid-parameter-from-writefile-or-readfile-8f2363d5-014f-bc3a-bc14-328374b99d56) but it barely helping in setting SACL.

*StackOverFlow wants me to add some details, so I will write some water here*

Maybe I messed up with some of the rights to provide to `SetSecurityInfo` and it is specifical to Named Pipes or I need to suspend it before change SACL?

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    SetSecurityPrivilage(TRUE); // Got SeSecurityPrivilage

    //HANDLE hPipe = CreateFile(L"C\:\\Users\\simp\\Desktop\\test", ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, NULL); // Folder SACL testing
    HANDLE hPipe = CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\pipe\\lsass", ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, NULL, NULL);
    if (hPipe != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {

        PACL pOldSACL = NULL;

        if (GetSecurityInfo(hPipe, SE_KERNEL_OBJECT, SACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, NULL, NULL, NULL, &pOldSACL, NULL) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {

            // SACL
            TRUSTEE trusteeSACL[1];
            trusteeSACL[0].TrusteeForm = TRUSTEE_IS_NAME;
            trusteeSACL[0].TrusteeType = TRUSTEE_IS_GROUP;
            trusteeSACL[0].ptstrName = (LPWCH)(L"Everyone");
            trusteeSACL[0].MultipleTrusteeOperation = NO_MULTIPLE_TRUSTEE;
            trusteeSACL[0].pMultipleTrustee = NULL;

            EXPLICIT_ACCESS explicit_access_listSACL[1];
            ZeroMemory(&explicit_access_listSACL[0], sizeof(EXPLICIT_ACCESS));

            explicit_access_listSACL[0].grfAccessMode = SET_AUDIT_SUCCESS;
            //explicit_access_listSACL[0].grfAccessMode = SET_AUDIT_FAILURE;
            explicit_access_listSACL[0].grfAccessPermissions = ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY;
            explicit_access_listSACL[0].grfInheritance = NO_INHERITANCE;
            explicit_access_listSACL[0].Trustee = trusteeSACL[0];

            PACL pNewSACL = NULL;

            if (SetEntriesInAcl(1, explicit_access_listSACL, pOldSACL, &pNewSACL) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
            {

                if (SetSecurityInfo(hPipe, SE_KERNEL_OBJECT, SACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, NULL, NULL, NULL, pNewSACL) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
                {
                    printf("%s\n", "SACL SetSecurityInfo IS WORKS");
                }
                else
                {
                    //Error handling        
                    printf("%s%d\n", "SetSecurityInfo SACL", GetLastError());
                }
                
              
                LocalFree(pNewSACL);
            }
            else
            {
                //Error handling        
                printf("%s%d\n", "SetEntriesInAcl", GetLastError());
            }
            LocalFree(pOldSACL);
        }
        else
        {
            //Error
            printf("%s%d\n", "GetSecurityInfo SACL", GetLastError());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //Error handling
        printf("%s%d", "Incorrect handle", GetLastError());
    }
    CloseHandle(hPipe);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the code is doing it's job. Then you compile and run this, you will change SACL of a pipe as well as a file. My mistake was in this part:

```
explicit_access_listSACL[0].grfAccessPermissions = ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY;
```

Which means that logs will be generate only when user will request ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY rights to a pipe, so change it to your needs. However, the reason behind 87 error is still unknown.